# выделение памяти в javascript

Tags: javascript

расскажите, как выделяется память в javascript в разных случаях

```
var a=1;
var string='string';
var array = [];
var bool = true;
var obj={
    a:1;
    }
```

не могу найти информацию о том, сколько выделяется для разных случаев, как выделяется, где выделяется.

Comment: >>где выделяется - Выделяется из кучи.
>>как выделяется - выделяется прозрачно.
>> сколько выделяется - выделяется столько сколько виртуальная машина посчитает нужным.

Comment: Все зависит от реализации, в разных движках может быть по разному.

Comment: К примеру число в js это 64-битный флот, но движок v8 в chrome оптимизирует маленькие значения до 32-бит. Так что тут четкого правила нет, все как сказали выше

Comment: Гуглите на тему "типизированные массивы". Вам приходилось встречать такие объявления: **var array = new Int8Array; var array = new Int16Array; var array = new Int32Array;**  Соответственно массивы, для каждой ячейки которых выделяется 1, 2, 4 байта памяти.